# python converting video to audio

Tags: python, bash, audio, video, ffmpeg

We are working on a project to convert video to audio, and this is the sample code:

```
from converter import Converter
from moviepy.editor import *
c = Converter()
clipv = 'g.mp4'
clipc = VideoFileClip(clipv).subclip(0,20)
conv = c.convert(clipc, 'clip5.mp3', {'format':'mp3','audio':{'codec': 'mp3','bitrate':'22050','channels':1}})
for timecode in conv:
    pass
```

However, it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
 File "del.py", line 7, in <module>
    for timecode in conv:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/converter/__init__.py", line 181, in convert
    if not os.path.exists(infile):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Of course, the other alternative is to use `ffmpeg`, but the problem is that the video in this case is an object instance, and as of now I am yet to find a way of passing object instances from python to bash.

The video object could be written as a video file, but that will lead to lots of time wastage, as the conversion takes place inside a loop.

It is quite time consuming to have to write the video file time and again, so as to easily extract audio from it.

I would highly appreciate any solution that will either help me get around the above error, or any that will allow me to pass the video `fileclip` object instance to bash `ffmpeg` as a variable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("myvideo.mp4").subclip(0,20)
clip.audio.write_audiofile("theaudio.mp3")
```

You can add a lot of parameters in write_audiofile (format, codec, bitrate, fps, etc.)

Comment: When I try this code I got following error: `NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling:
  imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()`

Comment: To solve simple: `import imageio  '''then'''  imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()`

Answer (score 5):

For those who get the following error while downloading "moviepy.editor" (*NeedDownloadError: Need ffmpeg exe. You can download it by calling: imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()*)

Just do this :

```
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Comment: its deprecated use "pip install imageio-ffmpeg" instead

Answer (score 0):

For future reference and as a complementary to the accepted answer, you could also choose a [bitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#MP3) for your audio! `"128K"`, `"192K"` and `"320k"` are the most common `bitrates` to choose from! Here's a sample of how you might want to achieve it:

```py
import moviepy.editor as mp

clip = mp.VideoFileClip("path/to/your/video.mp4")

clip.audio.write_audiofile(
    "path/to/save/your/audio.mp3",
    bitrate = "192k" # or it could be "128k" or "320k"
    )
```

**NOTE:**

- Depending on which `bitrate` you choose, the `size` and `quality` of the generated audio would vary!
- You could get the bitrate as an input from users instead of "hard coding" it to your script. You could do the same for the input and output paths too!