# how to handle multiple requests on a telegram bot in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

For example making a bot to convert mp4 to mp3, they send to my bot mp4 at the same time, now how to process it simultaneously and send to them at one time?

Comment: you can use ffmpeg in python as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448759/python-converting-video-to-audio/33449753)

Comment: you may try to run it in separated thread or multiprocess.

Comment: Asynchronous execution is the answer. Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540483/how-to-work-with-simultaneity-with-telegram-bot-python

Comment: thanks all for help me